# What is this site (Worldbuilding Meta Stack Exchange) for?

Tags: support, meta

I usually wouldn’t ask a question like this, purely because most of these Stack Exchange sites are self-explanatory. This site on the other hand just feels like a duplicate to the Worldbuilding one and what got me thinking even more is I have the same status on the Worldbuilding site.

So if anyone would be kind enough to let me know: what is this site and what is it used for?

Comment: Where you've posted right now is not a "duplicate" of Worldbuilding. [It's the Meta site for Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: You can tell because the meta sites have a washed-out colour scheme compared with their corresponding main sites. And it says "Meta" top left next to the worldbuilding title., and the URL includes the word. To switch between the two, use the burger-menu top right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As VLAZ says [worldbuilding meta](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) isn't for asking worldbuilding questions it's for asking questions about the worldbuilding site. Other websites may not make a distinction between, meta discussion, about the site, and the rest of the activity, or keep it in the same place but tag it differently. On the SO network the two are deliberately kept somewhat separate.
Your reputation and privleges from the main site automatically carry over and voting on meta will have no effect on your rep on either site.

If you encounter a technical issue, are unsure of some aspect of site policy, or want to propose a change to said policy, you can post on the meta site about that and keep the questions about building fictional worlds to the main site.

Coincidentally asking what's the difference between meta and the main site is a great example of a question that should be asked on meta and not the main site.